# After deploying a symfony 1.2 app, should i unfreeze the project in the remote host?

Tags: deployment, symfony1

just that. I suppose no.

Javi

Comment: Well, no. The *purpose* of freezing is to deploy symfony remotely...

Answer (score 0):

No you should not. A frozen project has all the important symfony files copied into the project directory. If you had the symfony enviroment on your remote/production host, there would be no need to freeze your project in the first place.